# WCF without adding service reference in vb

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I'm just a starter in silverlight and WCF. I came across a very good article [here](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/11/Understanding-WCF-Services-in-Silverlight-2) by  Miguel A. Castro which teaches to add the WCF manually. I have the contract service setup and the only thing I left is to get the data back from the service in the silveright. I have a hard time translate the code to vb.net.

```
                BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("/Person.svc");
                IPersonService personService = new ChannelFactory<IPersonService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
                //+
                AsyncCallback asyncCallBack = delegate(IAsyncResult result)
                {
                    Person person = ((IPersonService)result.AsyncState).EndGetPersonData(result);
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
                    {
                        spMain.Children.Add(new TextBlock
                        {
                            Text = person.FirstName 
                        });

                    });
                };
                personService.BeginGetPersonData("F488D20B-FC27-4631-9FB9-83AF616AB5A6", asyncCallBack, personService);
```

`AsyncCallback asyncCallBack = delegate(IAsyncResult result) {`

and

`this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate {`

How should that be written in vb.net?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the C# code converted to Vb.NET

```
Dim basicHttpBinding As New BasicHttpBinding()
Dim endpointAddress As New EndpointAddress("/Person.svc")
Dim personService As IPersonService = New ChannelFactory(Of IPersonService)(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel()
'+
Dim asyncCallBack As AsyncCallback = Function(result As IAsyncResult) Do
    Dim person As Person = DirectCast(result.AsyncState, IPersonService).EndGetPersonData(result)
    Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Function() Do

        spMain.Children.Add(New TextBlock() With { _
            Key .Text = person.FirstName _
        })
    End Function)
End Function
personService.BeginGetPersonData("F488D20B-FC27-4631-9FB9-83AF616AB5A6", asyncCallBack, personService)
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work. C#/VB converter you used do some funny things because it is not a human it can't understand everything...... Why do we have to remove "delegate" when the code is in vb?

Answer (score 0):

You can either break the code up into separate subs, doing something like this:

```
Dim asyncCallBack As AsyncCallback = AddressOf MyCallBack

Public Sub MyCallBack(ByVal Result As IAsyncResult)

    Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() AddTextBlock())

End Sub

Public Sub AddTextBlock()

    'code to add new textblock here

End Sub
```

or look at [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

```
Dim asyncCallBack As AsyncCallback = Sub(result As IAsyncResult)

                                     End Sub
```

and

```
Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()

                          End Sub)
```